# Use a Rollup plugin in the development environment only

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I'm trying to use the `rollup-plugin-copy` plugin to copy a file that contains data fixtures from  the src directory to the public directory for development purposes only. When rollup is bundling in the production environment, I don't want this to happen.

```
plugins: [
    resolve({
        mainFields: ['browser', 'module', 'main'],
        preferBuiltins: true,
        browser: true,
    }),
    () => {
        if (APP_ENV === 'development') {
            copy({
                targets: [
                    {
                        src: 'src/fixtures/list.js',
                        dest: './public',
                        transform: (contents) => contents.toString().replace('module.exports', 'var list'),
                    },
                ],
            });
        }
    }
],
```

I'm doing the above in my rollup config but it doesn't seem to work. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by creating a function that returns the an array of plugins and then used the generated list of array as the rollup plugin list.

```
const pluginConfig = (environment) => {
  const pluginList = [
    //...list of other plugins
  ];

  if (environment === 'development') {
      pluginList.push(
        copy({
          targets: [
            {
              src: 'src/fixtures/list.js',
              dest: './public',
              transform: (contents) => contents.toString().replace('module.exports', 'var list'),
            },
          ],
        })
      );
  }

  return pluginList;
};


export default [
  {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      input: 'src/index.js',
      output: [],
      plugins: pluginConfig(APP_ENV),
  },
];
```